# Dynamic Time Warping and non-stationarity of time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, similarities, dynamic-time-warping

Dynamic Time Warping ([DTW](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org/)) computes the optimal alignment between points of two time series.

If we consider two non-stationary time series (e.g. the first proportional to the second), is the DTW able to detect the similarity between the series although their non-stationarity?

Comment: In vanilla form DWT computes a measure over a minimal path along a matrix of similarity, stationarity is not a pre-condition to compute that, though depending on the algorithm it could be made to have different sensitivity due to non-stationarity, i.e., selecting different norms.